# Constructing a circle of radius $r$ passing through $P$ and tangent to a given line

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, plane-geometry

> Let $L$ be a line and $P$ be a point outside of the line. Given a radius $r$, construct a circle with radius $r$ that passes through $P$ and is tangent to the given line.

I know the center of the circle asked must be a point in the circle with radius $r$ and center $P$, but I don't know where to take it from there.

Comment: Note that the distance from the center to the line must be equal to the distance between the center and $P$.

Comment: @awllower Sorry, I'm not getting the hint. So far all I'm getting from this is that both $P$ and the intersection point of the line and circle must be on the circle.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A circle is the set of points with distance $r$ from the center.  You want to find the center that is distant of $r$ from $P$ and from $L$.

To be tangent to $L$, your circle must have its center at a distance of $r$ from $L$.  This constraints the center to be onto one the two lines parallel to $L$ at a distance of $r$ from $L$.

To contains $P$, your circle must have its center at a distance of $r$ from $P$.  This constraints the center to be onto the circle or radius $r$ and center $P$.

Hence your center must be at the intersection of the two constraints.

Answer (score 1):

### Analytical solution

General equation of the circle is

$$
(x-a)^2 +(y-b)^2 =r^2
$$

where $(a,b)$ is the centre of the circle. The radius is given. We need to find the centre $(a,b)$.

We are given a point $P=(p,q)$ that belongs to the circle, thus

$$
(p-a)^2+(q-b)^2=r^2
$$

This gives one equation for $(a,b)$. The second equation is given by the tangent line. Let $Ax+By+C=0$ be the tangent line. The condition for it to be tangent means that it has two coinciding common points with the circle. Or, alternatively, the equations:

$$(x-a)^2+(y-b)^2=r^2$$

$$Ax+By+C=0$$

have two coinciding solutions. This information should be enough to find $(a,b)$ and solve the problem.

**NB**: If you don't mind using a bit of calculus, it can help with the solution. Gradient to the circle at point $(x,y)$ is a vector $\{x-a,y-b\}$. This vector is perpendicular to the tangent line and, thus, is parallel to vector $\{A,B\}$. This gives a necessary, but not sufficient condition for the line to be tangent.

### Constructing the circle

This is actually easier than the analytical solution. I will describe the construction process, I hope it will be clear enough to be reproducible.

We are given point $P$ and line $l$ on the plane and the length of the radius $r$. The centre $O$ of the circle must lie: (a) in the same semi-plane as $P$ relative to $l$, (b) on the line $l_r$ parallel to $l$ and at the distance $r$ from $l$ and (c) at distance $r$ from $P$.

Line $l'$ is constructed by constructing two perpendicular lines to $l$ at some points $A$ and $B$ and constructing segments $AA'=BB'=r$ to the semi-plane containing $P$, then $A'B'=l'$.

To satisfy (c) the centre must lie somewhere on the circle of radius $r$ with centre at $P$. Find the intersection of the circle with $l'$ and you get the centre $O$.

**NB**: depending on the choice of $P$, $l$ and $r$ there can be either two solutions, one or none. Can you find the condition when there are the solutions?

Comment: I don't see how there can be two or no solutions. Could you elaborate on that? Intuitively it seems there will always be only one solution.

Comment: @MatheusAndrade consider $r$ being very small. Does the circle $(P,r)$ always cross the line $l'$? There actually can be a single solution that I originally missed. If you find the condition under which the circle is unique, you will see when no such circle can exist.